# If statements in for loop not qualifying vector in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I wrote a function in R to attach zeros such that any number between 1 and 100 comes out as 001 (1), 010 (10), and 100 (100) but I can't figure out why the if statements aren't qualifying like I would like them to.

```
id <- 1:11
Attach_zero <- function(id){

    i<-1
    for(i in id){
        if(id[i] < 10){
            id[i] <- paste("00",id[i], sep = "")
        }

        if((id[i] < 100)&&(id[i]>=10)){
            id[i] <- paste("0",id[i], sep = "")
        } 
        print(id[i])
    }
}
```

The output is "001", "2", "3",... "010", "11"

I have no idea why the for loop is skipping middle integers.

Comment: This functionality already exists: `sprintf('%03d', 1:10)` returns `[1] "001" "002" "003" "004" "005" "006" "007" "008" "009" "010"`.

Comment: The same with `formatC(1:10, flag=0, width=3)`, which returns `[1] "001" "002" "003" "004" "005" "006" "007" "008" "009" "010"`

Comment: Do you realise that the `i<-1` does nothing as it is after that written with `for (i in id)` which in turns gives `i` for each loop the *ith* value of `id` instead of an index? So if your `id` is `id <- c(1:3, 6:11)` you will have unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're assigning a character string (e.g. "001") to a numeric vector. When you do this, the entire `id` vector is converted to `character` (elements of a vector must be of one type).

So, after comparing `1` to `10` and assigning `"001"` to `id[1]`, the next element of `id` is `"2"` (i.e. character 2). When an inequality includes a character element (e.g. `"2" < 10`), the numeric part is coerced to character, and alphabetic sorting rules apply. These rules mean that both `"100"` and `"10"` comes before `"2"`, and so neither of your `if` conditions are met. This is the case for all numbers except `10`, which according to alphabetic sorting is less than `100`, and so your second `if` condition is met. When you get to `11`, neither condition is met once again, since the "word" `"11"` comes after the word `"100"`.

While there are a couple of ways to fix your function, this functionality exists in R (as mentioned in the comments), both with `sprintf` and `formatC`.

```
sprintf('%03d', 1:11)
formatC(1:11, flag=0, width=3)
# [1] "001" "002" "003" "004" "005" "006" "007" "008" "009" "010" "011"
```

For another vectorised approach, you could use nested `ifelse` statements:

```
ifelse(id < 10, paste0('00', id), ifelse(id < 100, paste0('0', id), id))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
id <- 1:11
Attach_zero <- function(id){
  id1 <- id
  i <- 1
  for (i in seq_along(id)) {
    if(id[i] < 10){
      id1[i] <- paste("00", id[i], sep = "")
    }
    if(id[i] < 100 & id[i] >= 10){
      id1[i] <- paste("0", id[i], sep = "")
    } 
  }
  print(id1)
}
```

Comment: It's correct. Output is: `> Attach_zero(id)
 [1] "001" "002" "003" "004" "005" "006" "007" "008" "009" "010" "011"`

Comment: Now it is, but the OP's function has other problems. Try `Attach_zero(20:30)`, for example. Shouldn't be iterating over `id` but over `seq_along(id)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you try your function with `id = c(1:3, 6:11)`:

```
Attach_zero(id)
##[1] "001"
##[1] "2"
##[1] "3"
##[1] "8"
##[1] "9"
##[1] "010"
##[1] "11"
##Error in if (id[i] < 10) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

What here happens is that the missing values are omitted because your `i` values says so. The `i<-1` does nothing as it is after that written with `for (i in id)` which in turns gives `i` for each loop the *ith* value of `id` instead of an index. So if your id is `id <- c(1:3, 6:11)` you will have unexpected results as showed. 
Just correcting your function to include all the elements of the id:

```
Attach_zero <- function(id){
    for(i in 1:length(id)){
        if(id[i] < 10){
            id[i] <- paste("00",id[i], sep = "")
        }

        if((id[i] < 100)&&(id[i]>=10)){
            id[i] <- paste("0",id[i], sep = "")
        } 
        print(id[i])
    }
}
Attach_zero(id)
##[1] "001"
##[1] "2"
##[1] "3"
##[1] "6"
##[1] "7"
##[1] "8"
##[1] "9"
##[1] "010"
##[1] "11"
```

Note the number 7 in this output.
And using sprintf as [jbaums](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24279973/2886003) says, including it in a function:

```
Attach_zero <- function(id){
 return(sprintf('%03d', id)) #You can change return for print if you want
}
Attach_zero(id)
## [1] "001" "002" "003" "006" "007" "008" "009" "010" "011"
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much for all the help everyone. Just starting this language and not used to not having to explicitly declare variables as with my previous programming experience. This discussion cleared many of my issues. Sincerest thanks.

Comment: If any of the posted answers helped mark it as useful, to help future visitors.